# Troubles grouping data by date

Tags: r, time-series

Trying to group my data by month and year but keep getting this error message:

> Error in object[[name, exact = TRUE]] :    object of type 'closure' is
>   not subsettable

This is my code:

```
passflow %>%
  group_by(txdate=floor_date(date,"month"))%>%
  summarize(flows=sum(flows))
```

This is my dataset:

```
 weekday     txdate flows month year
1       1 2012-01-02 24317     1 2012
2       2 2012-01-03 20116     1 2012
3       3 2012-01-04 11344     1 2012
4       4 2012-01-05 11621     1 2012
5       5 2012-01-06 18203     1 2012
6       6 2012-01-07 20430     1 2012
```

Comment: Don't name the variable in `group_by`. So do `group_by(txdate)`, or `group_by(floor_date(txdate,"month")`. Also, there doesn't seem to be a `date` variable in you dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the year and month in your `group_by` with `format`. This has the advantage of giving some more control over formatting in the output df (if you want it).

```
passflow %>%
  group_by(year = format(passflow$txdate, "%Y"), # group by year
           month = format(passflow$txdate, "%B")) %>% # group by month
  summarize(flows = sum(flows))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   year [1]
  year  month    flows
  <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 2012  February 38633
2 2012  January  67398
```

(I moved some data into Feb to check)

As pointed out by divibisan, you have a mistake in your OP:

```
passflow %>%
  group_by(txdate=floor_date(txdate,"month"))%>%
  summarize(flows=sum(flows))
```